# How to properly modularize Angular 4 w/ customizability?

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how to create components that can be customized from the calling component. As an example, I am trying to build a text input called textbox that can be passed things like maxlength, validation-messages[], etc. in the following manner:

```
<textbox maxlength="40" validation-messages="['This field is required','This field is too long']></textbox>
```

And the template for textbox.component would look something like:

```
<label for...></label>
<input ... />
<div *ngIf="field.invalid && (field.dirty || field.touched)">
<div [hidden]="field.errors.required">
<!--validation messages here-->
</div></div>
```

I have been attempting to accomplish this for a few days but can't seem to get it to work quite right. Using directives just leads me to dead ends (for example, changing innerHTML from the directive causes the *ngIf not to work correctly and the Validation messages to always be present, regardless of which lifecycle hook I use), and as far as I can tell, services can't be used to send data from the calling HTML to the receiving component, but I need to be able to send variables to textbox from the caller to change textbox's template and maintain modularity.

If anyone knows the proper way to accomplish something like the above, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried?

Could you make a plunkr? as a base you can use the following plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/fd7IHe4SGizzPPyNlDU9

Comment: Here is the basics of what I had when I was closest: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMcE0hC8NmAMRzByFVP0?p=info) Doesn't work (probably pathing and missing styles) but it gives you an idea of what I am working with hopefully. @DOMZE

Comment: I fixed your plunk so it works for others to see so that it compiles https://plnkr.co/edit/kZIJuJC5CCcD4OeNwtWW What are you trying to accomplish? what is your end goal?

Comment: The idea is to modularize text input which includes validation but the validation still needs to be customizable from the caller (in the plunkr, app.component.html calls textbox by <textbox [required-message]="['Blah Blah Blah','Test']"></textbox>). So the entire structure is the real goal.

Comment: Currently I  am looking into [this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms) and it is looking quite promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was in [this article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms). Simply put, use directive formatting, but just have the @Input in the component file. Like so:

Calling Component:

```
<textbox [maxlength]="40" [validation-messages]="['This field is required','This field is too long']></textbox>
```

Containing Component (Textbox.component.ts):

```
@Input validation-messages: string[];
@Input maxlength: number;
```

This way you can work with the inputs directly from the component.ts file and conditionally format the component.html file from there.